# PHP/MYSQL Displaying hiscores with a group by working but not as intended

Tags: mysql, sql

Output is displaying things by the username, and the correct score is there, but it wont grab the other data with it on the same row.

I've tried adding a group by with proof as well but it's not working. Adding a group by proof will just add another record in the output showing two hiscores when I really only want one to show per a user.

```sql
SELECT MAX(total) AS total, sUsername, proof, approved 
FROM userrankings 
WHERE category = 0 
GROUP BY sUsername 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

This is the output:

```
Rank: 1
User: Test User
Score: 2414
Proof: html site 1
```

However, in the database the score is correct, but the proof section should be HTML 2 because the 2nd entry has the highest score, not the first entry, but with the group by sUsername, it's forcing to only grab the very first entry rather than the entry I need it to be displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that, for each user, you want to pull out the record that has the highest `total`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the records of each user in a subquery, and do the filtering in the outer query:

```
SELECT total, sUsername, proof, approved 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        total, 
        sUsername, 
        proof, 
        approved,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sUsername ORDER BY total DESC ) rn
    FROM userrankings 
    WHERE category = 0      
) x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY total DESC
```

On previous versions of MySQL, one solution is to use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to ensure that only the relevant records are displayed,, like:

```
SELECT total, sUsername, proof, approved 
FROM userrankings u
WHERE 
    category = 0    
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM userrankings u1
        WHERE 
            u1.category = 0
            AND u1.sUsername = u.sUsername
            AND u1.total > u.total
    )
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: So the bottom code (cuz unf I had to use a webhost that doesn't support version mysql 8.0) it's returning the code order from lowest to highest rather than highest to lowest.

Comment: @Livvydoodlez: the ORDER BY clause was missing, I just added it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `GROUP_CONCAT` all the `proof`s:

```
SELECT MAX(total) AS total, sUsername, GROUP_CONCAT(proof ORDER BY total DESC), approved
FROM userrankings 
WHERE category = 0 
GROUP BY sUsername 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

And looking at `ORDER BY total DESC`, the first of proof should be your result

Comment: That outputs:
```
html proof 1, html proof 2
```

So essentially it's grouping ALL of the proofs together.

Comment: I admire your eagerness to contribute, but again, this query is profoundly flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for you comment. could you please tell me exactly how this query is flawed

Comment: @Livvydoodlez you could do this maybe: `GROUP_CONCAT(proof ORDER BY total DESC)`, this way the first concat'ed word would be the right proof

Comment: You have an a non-aggregated column in the SELECT that doesn't appear in the GROUP BY. Older versions of MySQL allow this (by default), but all other RDBMSs do not, as it returns an indeterminate result.